# Fill the grid - 2.0

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

> Can you fill this grid ? (Version 2.0 )

[image: Grid]

Text version

```
714523  
191303  
165088  
213443  
573211  
91?12?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing numbers are

> 6 and 7.

To find them, observe that

> on row $k$, the two digit number in the middle of the row is obtained by adding the two digit numbers to the left and right, adding $4\times(-1)^k$ to their sum and then dividing by 2.

Comment: You got it! Excellent!!!

Comment: (Please use spoilers here to preserve the mystery for other would-be solvers)